# What does the instruction 'wbnoinvd' do?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, cpu-cache

So, I found the instruction

> wbnoinv

at https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=0,152,5355,2791,2156,3801,4772,6164,6162,6166,6167,6102&othertechs=WBNOINVD.

So I was curious about if I can use it without OS privileges (just a user-land application), which kind of write back it does, if it really affect all the internal caches or in the case it doesn´t, which caches are affected, and what kind of data it 'writes back'.

So, I did a research on my own, and I didn´t find anything useful, just some requests that say that instruction was added in the Linux kernel with PCONFIG, around january of 2018, so it's not really up-to-date, and it didn´t answer my questions.

Comment: The instruction is not yet in the Intel SDM (not in my copies but they may not be updated) but it is in the ISA Extensions manual. It is privileged. The first line of the description reads: "*The WBNOINVD instruction writes back all modified cache lines in the processor’s internal cache to main memory
but does not invalidate (flush) the internal caches.*"

Comment: Wait Iris! Your question is actually much deeper than it seems! Intel doesn't document which caches are affected by `wbnoinvd`. One would expects all are but there a note warning about *different implementations*. Unfortunately testing this may be hard (impossible?) yet but still. If you wait a bit long a non-lazy-like-me person will likely provide a real answer ;)

Comment: I would expect this instruction to be similar to the `WBINVD` instruction but without invalidating the caches.  That instruction writes back all internal caches, then directs the external caches to also write back modified data (but does not wait for this to be complete).  The _different implementations_ note is applicable to future processors.

Comment: I'm struggling to find a plausible use case for `wbnoinvd`. For "ACID properties" for things like in-memory databases and file systems backed by non-volatile RAM; and for managing keys for multi-key memory encryption (e.g. changing pages from read/write to read-only before aliasing with a different key); it seems like extreme over-kill (relative to a finer-grained/better targeted series of `clflushopt`). Power management stuff (offlining CPUs, suspend/hybernate) aren't performance critical and `wbnoinvd` (instead of `wbinvd`) isn't likely to improve performance enough for anyone to care.

Comment: @MargaretBloom It writes back lines in all the data caches in the same coherence domain (i.e., NUMA node). One thing I'm not sure about is whether the external DRAM cache (when Optance DC is configured in memory mode) gets written back as well. It's not clear whether the term "external cache" refers to the outdated external SRAM caches or the new external DRAM caches. Regarding the compatibility note, this note also exists in the description of `WBINV` in all versions of the manual all the way back to 486. It's not clear to me what it means.

Comment: @Brendan It doesn't make much sense to me that `WBNOINVD` is useful for NVRAM (`CLWB` is the one useful for NVRAM). But I think you're right about the aliasing physical addresses use case. This is where performance can be improved using `WBNOINVD`, in contrast to using, for example, `WBINV`.

Comment: @HadiBrais Interesting! I'm not well versed in those subjects. I remember the eDRAM being attached to the L3 in Haswell and being moved near the memory controller in Skylake. Is that an external cache? The branding of Optane has always confused me: Optane DC persistence memory is a NVDIMM, the others seems just SSDs, either standalone or acting as other disks' caches. I guess. Are they considered caches in this context? Which CPUs had an off-die SRAM cache? Thank you!

Comment: @MargaretBloom I think an internal cache is one that is on-package and an external cache is one that is off-package. Yes, Optane DC is a DIMM and it can operate in two modes. In the Memory Mode, the DRAM DIMMs behave as direct-mapped caches, which become effectively an "external" cache and the NVDIMMs would be the main memory. eDRAM caches are on-package, so I don't think these are considered external caches. Some ancient processors such as the Pentium II had an off-package L2 SRAM cache, which was called an external cache. Overall, I find the description of `wbnoinvd` a little confusing.

Comment: @Brendan, the time required to execute wbnoinvd may be related to the size of the cache(s) being flushed, while the time for clwb is related to the size of the range of addresses being flushed. For very large ranges, wbnoinvd may be considerably faster.

Comment: @prl That's correct. When the number of cache lines to be written back is larger than some threshold, `wbnoinvd` is faster than a series of `clwb` instructions. The threshold highly depends on the processor and, in general, is over 1MB. Typically, when programming for NVRAM, atomically persisting such large number of bytes is not needed. The typical case is persisting a couple of cache lines, so `wbnoinvd` is rarely useful in that domain. BTW, the same goes for `wbinv` vs. `clflush`/`clflushopt`.

Comment: Other than that, `wbinv` (and potentially `wbnoinvd`) serialize the execution of all sibling logical cores (basically the whole physical core). That's an additional performance hit. Moreover, during the execution of `wbinv`, interrupts cannot be serviced and the resulting delay may not be acceptable.

Comment: @prl: Yes, `wbnoinvd` (and `wbinvd`) can be faster if you need to flush a huge area, but I still can't see a plausible use case where you do need to flush such a huge area (that's performance sensitive enough to justify the hassle of a CPUID check and "wbnoinvd not supported" fallback).

Comment: @MargaretBloom: It's better to think of eDRAM as a cache between the cache coherent bus and the RAM (and not between the CPU and a cache coherent bus like LLC). Essentially, there's no need for cache coherency between eDRAM and RAM (because everything, including PCI devices, that needs cache coherency has to go through eDRAM before it gets to RAM).

Comment: @HadiBrais:  I'm not sure about the "volatile RAM as cache for non-volatile RAM" case. I'd suspect that maybe the volatile RAM is used as a write-through cache and not a write-back cache, so that there's no need for cache coherency between the volatile and non-volatile RAM (it ends up like the eDRAM with "write-through" providing assurance that writes are persisted). However, it could act as an external write-back cache where it would need to honor additional control of external caches (and might break the whole point of `wbnoinvd` if it doesn't)

Comment: @HadiBrais Thank you, I've found a description of Optane DC PM in Memory Mode. In such mode the NV aspect of the NVDIMM is not used, so the DRAM (cache) doesn't need to be written back into the Optance memory.

Comment: @Brendan [The position of the eDRAM changed with Skylake](https://www.anandtech.com/show/9582/intel-skylake-mobile-desktop-launch-architecture-analysis/5), it wasn't like that before.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Although the NV aspect is not used, a line may still be evicted from the DRAM cache just like in a normal cache. In that case, it has to be written back to NVRAM if it's dirty. Now that you have mentioned it, it actually makes sense for all cache flushing/writeback instructions to not wait/stall until the (external) DRAM cache writes back all the data because this data need not be persistent and the DRAM cache is not in the persistent domain. In the memory mode, the DRAM cache works like a direct-mapped write-back cache, and it helps in absorbing expensive writes to Optane.

Comment: Looks like the opcode for 'wbnoinvd' is similar to the opcode generated by 'wbinvd' plus a REX prefix, which probably just says to the processor to don't invalidate the data after the write back. About which kind of data it writes on the main memory, is just as @Hadi Brais says, it writes all the lines of all the internal caches. Where is that data mapped on the DRAM? Intel didn't released where, and if it have fixed memory address or the data is just written at address free of other data, so who knows...

Comment: Also, it's worth to mention that the processor also write back the data at external caches, and it doesn't wait for the flush signal to keep the execution, it's just done by the hardware, wbinvd/wbnoinvd only initiate that process of writing-back and, depending whether the opcode is REX prefixed or not, flushing the external cache